# Dashcode localhost server fails

Tags: ios-simulator, dashcode

I write a dashcode program and run it to test. this should connect to  http://localhost:50853/index.html but fails to do so with a "could not connect to the server".
THis worked some months ago when i was last working on it but have done several update since then. Also i cannot see anywhere to tweek this address. looks as though it is fixed.

Comment: The project83 blog has a good post on this: http://www.project83.com/blog/how-to-test-iphone-websites-locally-with-the-iphone-simulator/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your /etc/hosts has a line like this.

`127.0.0.1  localhost`

This fixed my problem.